# Backend testing

Tags: qa-role, database

Backend testing is basically a database testing right? Can it be something else? I was asked that question and I have a hard time finding the right answer. Anyone has any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back-end and back-end testing per se is a complex mechanism. Basically anything that communicates with the server or database is back-end. Another definition can be anything *under the hood* is back-end. Server side is back-end, database level changes again back-end. So back-end testing isn't just database testing although db testing to a certain extent is a subset of back-end testing.

Furthermore, back-end testing is of tremendous importance as it is here that your business logic resides. API testing is again a very important part of back-end testing. So back-end testing is not mere database testing but a wider concept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Almost all web application will have  two components

1. Front end layer (GUI),
2. Backend layer that would contain business logic layer (API), and database layer

Backend testing means testing what we can not see, or we don't use the GUI.
You directly pass the request through some browser with the parameters needed for the function and get a response in some default forma e.g xml.JSON. You would also need to connect to database directly and verify the data using SQL queries. Debugging can be done through log files .
Backend testing is very important as

- it can uncover many defects at early stage reducing cost,
- it increases application stability and robustness
- improve the quality of application

Some of the Backend testing in regards to DB done in software testing services are following:

- Data validity
- Data integrity testing
- Performance check
- Stored procedures testing
- Triggers
- Functions testing
- Sequences testing
- Schema Database tables and associated Columns, Keys and Indexes
- Database server validations
- Validating data duplication